# Meaning of the root "ject"

Tags: english, etymology, latin, french, derivation

What does the root "ject" mean? It occurs in words such as "subject", "object", "project", "injection", "surjection", "bijection". As far as I know these words came to English from French and, in turn, from Latin. Prefixes "ob-", "sub-", "pro-" also came from Latin as Wiktionary says.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The root is Latin **iaciō** (throw, cast), whose supine is **iactum**.

Because of Latin ablaut (vowel change), prefixes like *sub-*, *ob-*, *pro-* trigger a vowel change to *-iectum.

Comment: More grammatical terms (many used in mathematics as well) and their [Latin derivations are available here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/wow/grammar.latin.html).

Comment: This isn't ablaut, as the term is usually used, but unstressed vowel weakening.

Comment: I'm not actually sure what the literature calls it -- possibly vowel mutation. But it's not called unstressed vowel weakening -- for one, the changed vowel in *proiectum* is actually stressed...

Comment: Naturally, it's not ablaut, no prefix triggers it, it's the very fact of derivation that does, it's just a historical vowel alternation. The rule for this **a** > **e** change is: Short **ă** in a closed non-final and in a closed final syllable of a multi-syllable word changes to short **ĕ**. E. g.: Princĕps < *prim-căp-s (primus + căpio 'first taking'), here in a closed final syllable ă > ĕ.

Comment: All of these “rules” are not so straight-forward. You have prō-icio, -iēcī, -iectus, but capio, cēpī, captus.

Comment: @jogloran This is about eight and a half years late, but yes, it is unstressed vowel weakening. The weakening happened at a pre-Latin stage when the language had fixed initial stress; so _ˈprōiaciō, ˈprōiactum_ become _ˈprōiciō, ˈprōiectum_ just like _ˈprincaps, ˈprincapes/-os_ (from _*ˈprīmo-cap-_) becomes _ˈprinceps, ˈprincipis_. Then later on, stress distribution changed to the Classical paenult-or-antepaenult position, but by then the vowels had already changed.